# NPGSQL relation "Blog" does not exist

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm trying to set up entity framework core for a project and i'm working through the entity framework core guide on the NPGSQL site: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html

and i'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\brandp3.DTINET\source\repos\EF-ModelFirst\EF-ModelFirst\Program.cs:line 15

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
PostgresException: 42P01: relation "Blog" does not exist

POSITION: 13
```

here's the code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            // Create and save a new Blog
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog); // error thrown here
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Display all Blogs from the database
            var query = from b in db.Blogs
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

The model:

```cs
    public class Blog
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }    

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }  
        
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }  
    }
```

and the dbcontext setup

```cs
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }  

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=mysecretpassword");
        }
    }
```

From what I understand the tables and relations should be created when I first run the program. At least the guide doesn't indicate that I need to push the schema to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand the tables and relations should be created when I first run the program.

EF Core doesn't automatically create the database schema for you - if you read this somewhere, can you please point to where that is? You'll have to either use [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) or [EnsureCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created) (though that's discouraged).

See also the [EF getting started guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-database), where minimal migration creation is shown.

Comment: I see now that i was using the ef core version of npgsql when I should be using the EF6 version. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'd highly recommend not using the old, non-core EF6, especially if you're starting a new project. That version is archived and no longer being worked on; EF Core is the actively-maintained project going forward.